# Symfony2 asset_version being added twice

Tags: css, symfony, assetic

My config.yml looks like so

```
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        assets_version: 2
```

And my twig template has this

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets  output='css/compiled/main.css'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css'
    %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset(asset_url) }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

This works but the output has the version param twice.

> > /css/compiled/main.css?v=2?v=2

I have no idea why this is happening and I am not overriding the `assets_version_format` either. I even searched my whole project for it just in case.

This only occurs though in my production env, dev is fine and works correctly with just one query param.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
```

(do not put `asset_url` within an `asset()` function)

Comment: Thanks. prod is now fixed, but dev has no param now.

Comment: Should work in both environments. Perhaps you need to clear the cache

Comment: I can cope with it I think. Thanks again.

Comment: There version is not added in the dev env but that's not a problem.